# Define function on object after object has been defined

Tags: javascript, function, object

In javascript, I know that if I have a function:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    return 'Hello World';
};
```

I can then extend the `myFunction` object and add properties to it like so:

```
myFunction.myProperty = 'Goodbye World';
```

And then I'm able to both call the function and access the properties:

```
// Returns 'Hello World'
myFunction();

// Returns 'Goodbye World'
myFunction.myProperty;
```

I want to know if there is a way to create a function on an already existing object; essentially the above but in reverse:

```
myFunction = {
    myProperty: 'Goodbye World'
};

myFunction ...{sprinkle some magic here}... = function() {
    return 'Hello World';
};

// Returns 'Hello World'
myFunction();

// Returns 'Goodbye World'
myFunction.myProperty;
```

Of course, just assigning the function to the `myFunction` object will overwrite the existing object already assigned to the variable.  Is there a way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: No, the only "callable" object type in JS is the Function. Other objects can't be made callable.

Comment: You can assign a new function as a property to `myFunction` object without overwriting it and calling that function while still keeping the original property

Comment: @BlueSkies This is what I suspected and is the clearest explanation - thanks.  If you put your comment in an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't take a normal object and use it like a function object as a function object is something different with some different capabilities.  The two objects are not the same.

You could create a function object, copy all the properties of the regular object and then assign the resulting function object back to the original name if you really wanted to define thing in this backward way.

```
// regular object defined first
var myFunction = {
    myProperty: 'Goodbye World'
};

// create function object
var tempFunction = function() {console.log("hi");}
// copy props from regular object to function object
for (var prop in myFunction) {
    if (myFunction.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        tempFunction[prop] = myFunction[prop];
    }
}

// assign new function object with copied props back to the original name
myFunction = tempFunction;

// now it's a function object that you can call
myFunction();

// or you can access its properties
var data = myFunction.myProperty;
```